# How can I upgrade from Developer edition to Standard SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server-2017

I had accidentally installed the wrong edition of SQL Server on our Live environment.

How can I upgrade from Developer edition to Standard edition?

Thank you .

Comment: @BeginnerDBA I have just upgraded it to the Standard edition but before I did that   i got warning message saying "The selected edition downgrade path is not valid .The source Developer edition and the target Standard edition is not supported path " .But changes from developer to standard succeded ,I hope that won't break anything in the future

Comment: Could you uninstall developer and install std?

Comment: @McNets If I'm going to do that I have been told to wipe out the whole server and reset everything again .

Comment: As Developer is identical to Enterprise, it is not an upgrade, technically. There is a chance a developed database is invalid in standard, i.e. using features not supported.